# Aplicando um :checked em uma div pai clicando na div filha

Tags: css, html5

Preciso deixar menu `checkbox` como o da imagem porem o meu background está na div pai e meu `checkbox` é um div filho como posso aplicar esse background em uma div pai cliando em um div filho

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<div class="bg-checkbox-dynamic -gray-light">
                                                            <div class="custom-controls-stacked d-block my-3">
                                                                <label class="custom-control custom-ctr material-checkbox">
                                                                    Link 1
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
                                                                    <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
```

Css:

```
.bg-checkbox-dynamic{
  background-color: $gray-dark;
  padding: 1px 15px;
  @include border-radius(15px);

}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .bg-checkbox-dynamic{
  background-color:lime!important;
  color:white
}
```

Comment: Só com JavaScript vc vai conseguir acessar um pai através do filho. O CSS faz o contrário, seleciona elementos filhos, irmãos e adjacentes.

Comment: @Sam Como ficaria isso ?

Comment: Não precisa de JS, da pra fazer com CSS, mas não da forma como vc está pensando, da para fazer com pseudo elemento, ou simplesmente colocando o checkbox antes do pai, já que ele vai ser ativado pelo click na label, e não no próprio checkbox

Comment: @hugocsl então eu nao consigo colocar o checkbox antes porque bagunça tudo pois estou estilizando ele a ideia é deixar na estrutura que montei como ficaria o css então

Answer (score 1):

Nessa estrutura não tem como fazer isso. O CSS não acessa elementos pai através de um descendente (elemento filho). Teria que usar JavaScript:

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for(let i of boxes){
   i.onclick = function(){
      
      let pai = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
      
      if(this.checked){
         pai.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
         pai.style.color = "white";
      }else{
         pai.style.backgroundColor = "white";
         pai.style.color = "black";
      }
      
   }
}
```

```css
.bg-checkbox-dynamic{
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 1px 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="bg-checkbox-dynamic -gray-light">
   <div class="custom-controls-stacked d-block my-3">
       <label class="custom-control custom-ctr material-checkbox">
           Link 1
           <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
           <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
       </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Veja que usei `.parentNode` 3 vezes para chegar na div que será alterada. Isso porque o checkbox está no 3º nível dentro dessa div. Mas você pode usar o método `.closest()` se quiser. O problema é que esse método não funciona em navegadores um pouco mais antigos. A vantagem dele é que, não importa o nível do elemento, ele irá buscar um elemento pai diretamente através de um seletor (classe, id, atributo etc.):

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for(let i of boxes){
   i.onclick = function(){
      
      let pai = this.closest(".bg-checkbox-dynamic");
      
      if(this.checked){
         pai.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
         pai.style.color = "white";
      }else{
         pai.style.backgroundColor = "white";
         pai.style.color = "black";
      }
      
   }
}
```

```css
.bg-checkbox-dynamic{
  background-color: gray-dark;
  padding: 1px 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="bg-checkbox-dynamic -gray-light">
   <div class="custom-controls-stacked d-block my-3">
       <label class="custom-control custom-ctr material-checkbox">
           Link 1
           <input type="checkbox" class="material-control-input">
           <span class="material-control-indicator"></span>
       </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maravilha funcionou porem a cor que tem que aparecer ao selecionar teria que ser um gradiente é possível ?

Comment: É possível, basta trocar "lime" pelo fundo que vc quiser. Talvez tenha que trocar tb a propriedade.